# How to handle timeout exception in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, xamarin

2021-01-19 18:34:32.877465+0530 REPORT[7165:380896] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [60: Operation timed out]
2021-01-19 18:34:32.886744+0530 REPORT[7165:380896] Connection 2: received failure notification
2021-01-19 18:34:32.889254+0530 REPORT[7165:380896] Connection 2: failed to connect 1:60, reason -1
2021-01-19 18:34:32.890389+0530 REPORT[7165:380896] Connection 2: encountered error(1:60)
2021-01-19 18:34:32.892589+0530 REPORT[7165:381682] Task .<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1001 [1:60])
2021-01-19 18:34:32.895246+0530 REPORT[7165:380952] Task .<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002b5eca0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey

Comment: Need more detail on your question. Please share detailed code example that shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar?

```
try {
//code
}
catch (TimeoutException) {
//exception handler
}
```

Comment: how to minimise time of timeout exception like 10 second.it take 2 mint about

Comment: i also chech server rechability problem.when reachability server then work .other wise it shows error through Aleart dialouge.how?

Comment: For the first question, set the request.timeout property. For the second question, check the result of server and give different response.